# Custom font in Wordpress doesn´t work fine on Apple devices - How can I fix this?

Tags: android, ios, wordpress, fonts

I have following problem. My custom font in Wordpress, Wittenberg and Drunk Text Wide Medium, work fine in Android devices as well as in Chrome and Firefox on a PC, but not on the new Safari 14.0 version as well on all browsers in iOS devices.

It only happens with special characters like ¿ or letters with accent marks. For example I will attach some screenshots:

[First example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fjH1v.jpg)
[Second example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mto41.jpg)

How can I fix this issue?

Answer (score 1):

Text may not display correctly if the web page uses characters that are not part of the default text encoding and the page does not indicate the correct encoding.

Is your page encoding in UTF-8 ?

https://support.apple.com/fr-fr/guide/safari/ibrw1031/mac

Comment: Yes, it´s predefined as UTF-8